Progressive matrices with black and white dots (Matrigma)
Will anyone explain how they solved these puzzles? I do not understand.



In only have time to go through the first figure, but I suspect the second one is similar logic, but with a slight twist.

Logic:
First: If same colored dots are in the same column, then subtract. If they are in different columns, then add.
The end column has the same top/bottom orientation as the middle column. I.e. if black is on top in the middle, then the black is on top in the last, and vice versa.
Walk through for first figure:
Top row:
All dots are in opposite columns, so all dots are added.
The black dots are on the top in the middle column, so the black dots are on top in the last column.
Middle row:
All black dots are in different columns, so these should be added. The circles on the left and right should be subtracted from eachother.
The black dots are on the bottom in the middle column, so the blacks should be on the bottom in the last column.
Bottom row:
The black in the left column should be kept, while the others should be removed. The circle in the middle should be removed, while the others kept.
The black dots are on the top in the middle column, so the blacks should be on top in the last column.
Therefore, the right figure must have one black dot on the top right, and one circle on either sides in the bottom row.

Second one is similar, but instead of where black dots are in middle, it's where they are in first column (at least from a cursory glance).
